# Import custom pipe Ionic 4

Tags: angular, pipe, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 5.2.7 and create a custom pipe **icons-category** with a **Pipes.Module** (I'm really not using it anywhere) and I'm trying to use it in my **modal-icon- expenses.page** but when I use it I have this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'iconsCategoria' could not be found ("

        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let im[ERROR ->]agen of iconPath | iconsCategoria:'asdasd'">
                <ion-item button="true" color="aqua" lin"): ng:///ComponentsModule/ModalIconGastosPage.html@6:44
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11188)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25721)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25709)
    at compiler.js:25653
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25653)
    at compiler.js:25566
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I need to import the Pipes Module somewhere.

Right now I have my modules, pages and my pipe in this way ...

**icons-categoria.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'iconsCategoria'
})
export class IconsCategoriaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(iconsArray: any [], categoria?: string): any[] {

    console.log(categoria);

    return iconsArray;
  }

}
```

**modal-icon-gastos.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ModalIconGastosPage } from './modal-icon-gastos.page';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../../Components/components.module';
import { IconsCategoriaPipe } from '../../../Pipes/icons-categoria.pipe';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ModalIconGastosPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    IconsCategoriaPipe
  ],
  declarations: [ModalIconGastosPage, IconsCategoriaPipe],
})
export class ModalIconGastosPageModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ComponentsModule } from './Components/components.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, ComponentsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**modal-icon-gastos.page.html**

```
<app-header [titulo]="'Elegí un Icono'"></app-header>

<ion-content color="aqua">
    <ion-grid fixed>

        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let imagen of iconPath | iconsCategoria:'asdasd'">
                <ion-item button="true" color="aqua" lines="none">
                    <img class="galeria icono" src="/assets/icons/{{imagen.path}}">
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: seems you did everything correctly, can you please create a stackblitz for that?

Comment: Sorry, It's the first time I use Stackblitz, Does this help you? https://stackblitz.com/github/EtcGonza/ControlGastos

Comment: yeah, some how, you don't need to import your whole project, you just can create some components to reproduce your issue, any way, your code there is different, you didn't add pipe to your pipe module providers and also you didn't import pipeModule in appModule (or any other modules)

Comment: My Pipemodule is not imported anywhere. But my pipe It's imported into my PipeModule. And my pipe It's imported in modal-icon-gastos.module.ts and then I use it in my modal.icon-gastos.html.

Comment: then same module should also provide it

Comment: My Pipe Module Should I import it to my providers or declarations? And in the app.module?

Comment: Sorry, it only need to be added to declaration, providers is not needed

Comment: This is my modal-icon-gastos.module.ts. This is what do you mean?

`@NgModule({
  imports: [

  ],
  providers: [
    IconsCategoriaPipe
  ],
  declarations: [ModalIconGastosPage, IconsCategoriaPipe, PipesModule],
})`

Comment: you don't need to add it to providers

Comment: check this simple example I created for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nanxla

Comment: and this if you want to have a seperate pipeModule
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwkjch

Comment: check examples I provided

Comment: It works Thanks!

Comment: Great, then please mark my post as answer, in case somebody else has same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a module for your pipes you need to declare and export the pipe in that module, then import that module in other modules you need

please see this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwkjch